# Select Rows based on a unique condition

Tags: mysql, sql

Input
I would like to get all the details of ID's whose prev is 'SC' and if its inserted first for that ID

Table1:

| id | Prev | Next | Time_inserted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | MA | BP | 9:00 |
| 1 | BP | SC | 9:01 |
| 2 | MA | AP | 9:02 |
| 2 | BP | MA | 10:00 |
| 3 | SC | AP | 11:00 |
| 3 | AP | BP | 11:01 |
| 5 | SC | AP | 12:00 |

So my Expected output is

| id | Prev | Next | Time_inserted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | SC | AP | 11:00 |
| 3 | AP | BP | 11:01 |
| 5 | SC | AP | 12:00 |

Since For Id's 3 & 5 the first inserted row in Prev is SC

This is what I tried so far,

```
with cte1 as  (select id
from Table1
where prev= 'SC' ) ,

 data as (select a.*, b.id as uno, row_number() over (partition by a.id, time_inserted ORDER BY a.time_inserted asc) as rn
from Table1  a
left join cte1 b on a.id= b.id
where prev = 'SC' ),

intermediate_D as(
select a.*, a.id
from data a
where rn = 1 )

select *
from intermediate_D a
join Table1 b on a.id = b.id
```

But the expected output is not achieved

Comment: Why is 2 excluded?

Comment: Sorry, edited the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `first_value()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             first_value(prev) over (partition by id order by time_inserted) as first_prev
      from table1 t
     ) t
where first_prev = 'SC';
```